# Cumulative multiplication with window functions, 'exp' is not a valid windowing function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions, exp

Is it possible doing cumulative multiply(below query) with window functions

```
    select Id, Qty
    into #temp
    from(
            select 1 Id, 5 Qty 

            union   

            select 2, 6

            union   

            select 3, 3
    )dvt

    select 
    t1.Id
    ,exp(sum(log( t2.Qty))) CumulativeMultiply
    from #temp t1
    inner join #temp t2 
        on t2.Id <= t1.Id
    group 
    by t1.Id
    order 
    by t1.Id
```

Like:

```
select 
        t1.Id
        ,exp(sum(log( t2.Qty))) over (partition by t1.Id order by t1.Id rows between unbounded preceding and current row )  CumulativeMultiply
        from #temp t1
        inner join #temp t2 
            on t2.Id <= t1.Id
```

But get error:

> The function 'exp' is not a valid windowing function, and cannot be used with the OVER clause

**Update:**
Result that actually I want:

```
Id          CumulativeMultiply
----------- ----------------------
1           5
2           30
3           90
```

Comment: You've just got your bracketing wrong - you want the `OVER` to apply to the `SUM`, so it needs to be *inside* the brackets for the `EXP`.

Comment: `exp()` is not an aggregate, so it can't be used as a window function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need of self join  for `Sum Over(Order by)` to find  the previous records and multiply it

```
 select  
        Id
        ,exp(sum(log( Qty))
        over (order by Id )) CumulativeMultiply from #temp
```

Comment: I tried the codes (not exactly same but quite similiar). It still reminds that ERROR: 'exp' is not a valid window function

Answer (score 1):

Only aggregation function are valid windowing functions.

I didn't test the code, but you need to separate the 2 in a way:

```
SELECT Id, exp(cm) CumulativeMultiply
FROM (
select 
        Id
        ,sum(log(Qty)) over (partition by Id order by Id rows between unbounded preceding and current row )  cm
        from #temp
) d
```

Comment: `Sum Over(Order by)` does not need self join to find the previous records and multiply it.

Comment: @Prdp correct me if i am worng...I guess,we can not use order by in case of aggregate window functions...like sum over(order by),count over(order by) ...etc..am i right?

Comment: @balaji You can use ORDER BY with SUM and while normally it doesn't make any sense, then when you are doing running you kind of have to specify order of rows.